# Detecting if there are 3 same letters next to each other

Tags: python

I want to detect if there are three of the same letter next to each other in a string.

For example:

```
string1 = 'this is oooonly excaple'   # ooo
string2 = 'nooo way that he did this' # ooo
string3 = 'I kneeeeeew it!'           # eee
```

Is there any pythonic way to do this?
I guess that a solution like this is not the best one:

```
for letters in ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', ..., 'zzz']:
    if letters in string:
         print(True)
```

Comment: Can you use regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the best ways to tackle these simple pattern problems is with regex

```py
import re

test_cases = [
    'abc',
    'a bbb a',    # expected match for 'bbb'
    'bb a b',
    'aaa c bbb',  # expected match for 'aaa' and 'bbb'
]

for string in test_cases:
    # We use re.findall because don't want to keep only with the first result.
    # In case we want to stop at the first result, we should use re.search
    match = re.findall(r'(?P<repeated_characters>(.)\2{2})', string)
    if match:
        print([groups[0] for groups in match])
```

Result:

```py
['bbb']
['aaa', 'bbb']
```

Answer (score 2):

you dont have to use regex but solution is little long for something as simple as that

```
def repeated(string, amount):
    current = None
    count = 0
    for letter in string:
        if letter == current:
            count += 1
            if count == amount:
                return True
        else:
            count = 1
            current = letter
    return False

print(repeated("helllo", 3) == True)
print(repeated("hello", 3) == False)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group similar letters and then check the length of each group:

```py
from itertools import groupby

string = "this is ooonly an examplle nooo wway that he did this I kneeeeeew it!"
for letter, group in groupby(string):
    if len(list(group)) >= 3:
        print(letter)
```

Will output:

```
o
o
e
```

If you don't care for the letters themselves and just want to know if there ***was*** a repetition, take advantage of short-circuiting with the built-in [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) function:

```
print(any(len(list(group)) >= 3 for letter, group in groupby(string)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression:

```
import re

pattern = r"(\w)\1{2}"

string = "this is ooonly an example"

print(re.search(pattern, string) is not None)
```

Output:

```
True
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using regex? - [`([a-z])\1{2}`](https://regex101.com/r/bgcWyj/2)

```py
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r'([a-z])\1{2}', 'I kneeew it!', flags=re.I)
<re.Match object; span=(4, 7), match='eee'>
```

[`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) will return `None` if it doesn't find a match, otherwise it'll return a match object, you can get the full match from the match object using `[0]` on it.

Comment: @JakubDóka `re.I` should take care of that

Answer (score 0):

```
string1 = 'nooo way that he did this'

for i in range(0,len(string1)-2):
     sub_st = string1[i:i+3]
     if sub_st[0]*3 == sub_st:
          print('true')
```

`print` statement is from your example.
`sub_st[0]*3` clone fist character in the `sub_st` combine those into single string. If original `sub_st` and clone one same it means `sub_st` carries the same latter 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

We can define following predicate with [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) + [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) functions like

```py
from itertools import groupby

def has_repeated_letter(string):
    return any(len(list(group)) >= 3 for _, group in groupby(string))
```

and after that use it

```
>>> has_repeated_letter('this is oooonly example')
True
>>> has_repeated_letter('nooo way that he did this')
True
>>> has_repeated_letter('I kneeeeeew it!')
True
>>> has_repeated_letter('I kneew it!')
False
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a general answer for n repetitions you can just iterate through the string and print true if previous character and next character are equal to current character, excluding the first and last character.

```
text = "I kneeeeeew it!"

for i in range(1,len(text)-1):
    if text[i-1] == text[i] and text[i+1] == text[i]:
        print(True)
        break;
```

Comment: Can also simply be `text[i-1] == text[i] == text[i+1]`